# Annotating REST web service in Java EE 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am making a web service with Java EE 6. From what I understand you can annotate either the local interface with the @Path/@GET etc. annotations or the no-interface bean. I wonder if it is common to make two interfaces; one for the web services with the annotations and another one for the local interface? Or do you just add them on the local interface?

Comment: You should add more details, like what framework you're using, as there are many types of annotations. Also, a code example would be extremely helpful and put things in context. Also, what is your goal with this? What are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, your asking if you should define an interface just for specifying the annotations. I'm not sure what the advantages would be of doing this, unless you had a really complex project and foresee yourself replacing the Web service annotations with another library. This library would have to be on its virtual deathbed in terms of future support, or there would need to be clear evidence that our CTO would be changing technologies for me to consider this strategy.

For most projects, this seems to be somewhat of an overkill, especially if you already have an interface defined for your controller that you can add those annotations to. As a colleague on your project, I wouldn't want to have to check 3 different files for annotations for 1 class, unless there was a very compelling reason to do so.

With that said, if you wanted to add the annotations to your interface or your subclass, [this is supported in this example](http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.4/rest/RESTAnnotateInherit.html). However, I think you would want to be sure to create a clear standard, either all your REST annotations are on the interface or all of your annotations are on the subclass. Mixing and matching them could get confusing for someone new to the project.

Without actually seeing your code and how complex it is, I can't tell you which method would be best for your project. The important thing is to balance consistency with flexibility. In summary, Java gives you plenty of rope, which equals flexibility, but you can also hang yourself with that rope if you're not careful. :)